# ¿Error de sintaxis al importar Textblob y matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: matplotlib, flask, python-3.7, vscode, spyder

Estoy tratando de hacer un proyecto en Python con Flask, en Spyder funciona sin problema, pero en VSCode, al intentar importar Textblob y matplotlib.pyplot en consola me da un error de sintaxis, ya reinstalé Textblob y matplotlib en repetidas ocasiones y sigo teniendo los siguientes errores en consola

Al importar Textblob:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "App.py", line 5, in
>   
>       from textblob import TextBlob   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\textblob__init__.py", line 2, in
>   
>       from .blob import TextBlob, Word, Sentence, Blobber, WordList   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\textblob\blob.py", line 28, in
>   
>       import nltk   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk__init__.py", line 128, in
>   
>       from nltk.collocations import *   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\collocations.py", line 35, in
>   
>       from nltk.probability import FreqDist   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 333
>       print("%*s" % (width, samples[i]), end=" ")
>                                             ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

y al importar matplotib.pyplot:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "App.py", line 6, in
>   
>       import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 115, in
>   
>       _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends__init__.py", line
>   63, in pylab_setup
>       [backend_name], 0)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       from . import tkagg  # Paint image to Tk photo blitter extension.   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\tkagg.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       from six.moves import tkinter as Tk   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 203, in load_module
>       mod = mod._resolve()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
>       return _import_module(self.mod)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
>       **import**(name)   File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 38, in 
>       import FixTk   File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\FixTk.py", line 68, in 
>       import _tkinter ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 no es una aplicaci¾n Win32 vßlida.

Uso los mismos imports en Spyder y el programa corre con total normalidad, así que no entiendo cuál es el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te está sucediendo probablemente, es que tienes varias versiones de Python instaladas.

En el caso del error de vscode, puedes ver que siempre te da este error

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py .... SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Estás ejecutando el programa con Python 2, y tú puede que lo tengas escrito con la sintaxis de python 3. Debes cambiar la versión de python que estás usando, y lo puedes hacer:

- En la parte inferior izquierda de vscode, donde aparece la versión que estás usando y puedes cambiarla.
- En "settings" puedes cambiar la opción "python.pythonPath" y poner el path donde se encuentra tu versión de python 3.7 .